# How do I make my object/camera solve correct? It seems blender can't figure out my cameras focal length

Tags: camera, motion-capture

[Here's a recording of the current (wrong) object solve.](https://youtu.be/8q15kikyrn0)

I have tried adding more markers and even manually changing each weight of each track but I can't get a solve error lower then this and when I look at the motion of the solve compared to the actual motion it's completely wrong.

I the perspective motion model and matched it to the previous frame.

I used an iphone 12 pro's front camera to film this but I can't find the camera settings for it anywhere.

Comment: Hello, we can't see your video as it is set to private

Comment: I seemed to have forgotten to put the video as unlisted, it's fixed now.